# perl Email::MIME not working intermittent

Tags: perl, email

the following code sometimes work, and sometimes do not. It is runnign on linux, where postfix is installed, i disabled it and stopped the service. does this need postfix to run?

when i run this test code in terminal i get no error and *no* email.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use Email::MIME;
    use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);

        my $sub='test';
        my $exitCode=0;
        my $emailTo='raxxxx@xxxx.com';
        my $bcc='';

        if ($exitCode == 0){$exitCode = '';}

        my @mesgBody = ("test\n","email\n");
        my $message = Email::MIME->create(
              header_str => [
                From    => '"Rajeev" <'.$emailTo.'>',
                To      => $emailTo,
                Subject => $sub,
              ],
              attributes => {
                'X-Priority' => 1,
                'X-MSMail-Priority' => 'High',
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => 'ISO-8859-1',
              },
              body_str => "@mesgBody"."\n".$exitCode,   #old   body_str => $sub."\n".$mesg."\n".$exitCode,
            );

        #sendmail($message);
        if ($bcc eq ''){
            my $result=sendmail(
                $message,
                {
                    from => '"Rajeev" <'.$emailTo.'>',
                    to   => [$emailTo],
                }
            );
print "result=".Dumper($result)."\n";
        } else {
            sendmail(
                $message,
                {
                    from => '"Rajeev" <'.$emailTo.'>',
                    to   => [$emailTo, $bcc],
                }
            );
        }
```

output:->
result=$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'Email::Sender::Success' );

so if this is success, why am i not getting any email?

I also see *nothing* in system logs.

thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where you check the outcome of the sendmail() calls.  Have you seen http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Sender-1.300016/lib/Email/Sender/Manual/QuickStart.pm#in_case_of_error ?

Comment: thx. with modified code. i get: $ test.pl              
result=Email::Sender::Success=HASH(0x1b655e0)

Answer (score 0):

```
# service postfix start
```

solved the problem.